# How to use numberFromString when UITextField has currency value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have an 'amount' input field that takes a number value that I wish to display as a currency within the input field itself. This I seem to be able to do with no issues.

I then use this value in a calculation and output as a currency value. Again this works fine the first time as it initially sees it as a double and not currency.

My problem comes when I try and reuse the value in the 'amount' input field, as the value is being seen and no longer a double because of the currency symbol etc.

Any suggestions?

**Edited below based on suggestions:**

```
    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

    var numberOfPlaces = 2.0
    var multiplier = pow(10, numberOfPlaces)

    var enteredAmount = formatter.numberFromString(finalAmount.text)?.doubleValue ?? 0.0

   enteredAmountLabel.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(enteredAmount)

   finalAmount.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(enteredAmount)
```

Using these amends the calculations work the first time anything is entered into the field. If you try a calculation when the field is populated it resets the field to $0.00

If I amend to:

```
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
```

Everything works as expected but the amount input field no longer displays as currency.

I am trying to provide screenshots but I do not have enough reputation points.

Comment: Trying this I get the error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I tried amending to ? instead of ! and it then gets me to enter ! wherever I have declared the variable in my calculations. The end result is still the same as it errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the line that gives you trouble?

```
var enteredAmount = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(finalAmount.text)!.doubleValue
```

It looks like you've got the right idea. You can use a number formatter to convert a value to a formatted string for display, or to convert a formatted string to a value.

I would expect that code to work.

Is that line giving you a compile error? An error at runtime? Not giving the value that it should?

### EDIT:

@LeonardoSavioDabus pointed out the problem. That line should use the number formatter you created above:

```
var enteredAmount = formatter.numberFromString(finalAmount.text)!.doubleValue
```

And you really shouldn't use force unwrapping like that. You should use the nil coalescing operator:

```
var enteredAmount = formatter.numberFromString(finalAmount.text)?.doubleValue ?? 0.0
```

### EDIT #2:

Here in the US, this code works perfectly in a playground:

```
import Foundation

var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let moneyString = "$12.93"

var enteredAmount = formatter.numberFromString(moneyString)?.doubleValue ?? 0.0

enteredAmount += 0.07

var newString = formatter.stringFromNumber(enteredAmount)
```

(I stripped out all the locale stuff to make it simpler.)

### EDIT #3:

Your locale code doesn't make sense to me.

```
for identifier in ["en_US" , "en_UK" , "en_US","fr_FR"] {
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: identifier)
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
}//end of locale detection for currency and decimal formatting
```

That code looks like it loops through 3 different values of `identifier` and assigns 3 different locales to your formatter, and the same max/min digit counts (both 2). The way I read that code, it's going to assign first the US locale, then the UK local, then US English again, and then finally French from France. So at the end of the loop the locale will be set to "fr_FR". That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Hi Duncan, Yes This is the line I am constantly messing with. It initially loads but then gives the following error when the calculation tries to run a second time. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You should use the formatter you have defined NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle otherwise it won't identify the currency symbol

Comment: Oh snap. I didn't notice that he wasn't using his custom formatter. Off to edit my answer...

Comment: I have tried the above and while the app will compile it errors when you try to open it. function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)

Comment: Thanks Duncan I am working through this now. You are correct that Locale seems to just use the last currency in the list. I was going to post that as a separate issue as I appear to have that implemented incorrectly.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Configure the formatter based on the current locale?

Comment: I have now implemented as you say above and the amount field just defaults to $0.00 regardless of what is entered. If I use DecimalStyle instead of CurrencyStyle then everything works as expected for the calculations and output labels but the text in the amount field is just the numbers entered '25.00'.

Comment: I am trying to display the numbers entered into the amount field as a currency value yet still be able to use it as a double for calculations. Then yes my next step is for the currency symbol to change depending on user location.

Comment: So, if the user is entering numbers without currency symbols, and then you want to do calculations and output the result with the currency symbol, you'll need 2 number formatters. One for the decimal format (no currency) input, and in currency format for the output.

Comment: I have updated my initial question so hoping it now makes more sense. I want the numbers a user inputs into the field to be displayed in the same field as a currency amount. so once entered the input field would display as $10.00

Comment: Your usage flow isn't very clear. Does the user enter amounts that include currency symbols? If so, you need a number formatter that's set to currency to parse the input. If not, you need one that's set to decimal format. Same goes for output. If you want to display a value as currency, use a currency formatter. Otherwise use a decimal formatter. You probably need both. (Actually you can probably convert decimal values directly to doubles using the NSString doubleValue method, without needing a number formatter at all.)

Comment: I know I am not explaining it the best and screenshots would explain it better. The user enters numbers and decimals using the decimal keypad. Its when they touch outside the input field I want the numbers they have entered to then display as currency within that input field. Behind the scenes I am using the values entered as a double to perform calculations and output as a currency value to a label.